# i want to process the same file multiple times in apache camel2

Tags: apache-camel

My requirement is to process the same file multiple times in Apache camel 2. how can i achieve this?

if I use noop=true then idempotent will be set to true. Otherwise file will be moved to the other directory.

Comment: what do you mean by process multiple times ? is the task going to be same or different ? do you want it to process again because some data will be appended to the file after some time like a log file ? please state some more details about your use case

Comment: lets take an example i have abcd.xml file and i am processing it. later some time i have to process the same file(abcd.xml) again.

Comment: that part i got from your question, my question to you is why do you want to process it again ? will the processing logic be same for 2nd time ?

Comment: no the logic is different.

Comment: so just send the file to a different route for 2nd processing or multicast at same time and have delays in processing.

Comment: but the initial steps are same. so i am processing in the same route and redirect to other route. if i have not used the noop=true then the file is moved to the .camel directory

Comment: please edit your question for details. List the steps of processing, indicate what is different in 2nd step of processing and so on. Also tell about the state of file is it going to be same, or will be changed by some external source or by earlier processing itself. It is very hard to help you right now because your question is unclear

Comment: I am polling the file using consumer template. In first process i will check for schema valid. after that some process(third party) will be taken places. based on the output of that process, i will be again poll that file for further processing.   the state of the file will remain same.

Comment: i guess you are waiting for third party to give a go ahead for further processing, so you can make that a blocking call and when it returns proceed accordingly.